# Set PHP variable from selected <option> in dropdown

Tags: php, variables, drop-down-menu

I have an index.php that contains two `<select>` dropdowns, both of which are populated from the MySQL database by functions in a functions.php file that is included into the index file.

The first box is populated like so:

```
function getCities() {
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT city FROM nights";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $items = array();

    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
            $items[] = array( $row[0], $row[1] ); 
            echo "<option value='" . $row['city'] . "'>" . $row['city'] . "</option>";
        }         
    }
}
```

What I want to do is set either the value of the selected `<option>` (for my present purposes, there is only one `<option>` in the dropdown) or its name/ID as a PHP variable so it can be used elsewhere. I've tried using `$row['city']` and putting the second function inside the while loop but that didn't work.

Comment: Could you assign it to an array? Such as $cities[] = $row['city'];  then you could do return $cities;

Comment: can you post a vardump of a $row ?

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively easy and I think you are over thinking this,

```
function getCities() {
    $query = "SELECT city_id, city FROM nights";

    $rows = $db->fetch_all_array($query);
      foreach($rows as $row){
    echo "<option value='$row[city_id]'>$row[city]</option>";
}
```